# How to call this function?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a function in Saves.java class and i want to call this function in the other Import.java class, how doing it ?
Here is the code of the function:

```
public void updatelv(Activity activity) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.fileName);
        fileDir = "" + preferences.getString("login", "") + "."+ preferences.getString("marque", "") + ".";
        list = myIO.ReadFilePerLine(getApplicationContext(), fileDir+fileName);
        ListView L = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, list);
        L.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

I think that i have to do this :  `Saves save=new Saves();`
And after, how to call the updatelv(activity) function ?

Thank you.

the import.java class called when pressed in a menu Import" button(in Saves.java class):

```
case R.id.importer:
  Import myImport = new Import(this);
  myImport.transfer();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to accomplish what you're looking for.

Option #1:

```
Saves save = new Saves();
save.updatelv(this);
```

Option #2:

Make your `updatelv()` method `static` (most useful in a Tool class, where you have stuff that never touches the UI views):

```
public static void updatelv(...) {}

//...

Saves.updatelv(this);
```

Comment: Lannér: Import class is not an activity. it just import a data file then want to update the UI .

Comment: Lannér:This function(updatelv) i use it when want to update the UI. me, i just want to import a data file then automatically "refresh" the UI with new imported data! i hope that you understand what i'd like to say...

Comment: There's no problem here. You can use the method you prefer

Answer (score 0):

```
Saves save=new Saves();
save.updatelv(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it with the Saves object you just created (assuming you already have an Activity object named activity):

```
save.updatelv(activity)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an object of type Activity ready and then:

```
  save.updatelv(activityObj);
```

should do it.

Comment: the import.java class is not an activity. so... ? :\

Comment: So where are you getting activities from? What is an Activity? The code that is calling this function will need a reference to an activity if it wants to call this function.

Comment: This function(updatelv) i use it when want to update the UI. me, and in this case,i just want to import a data file then automatically "refresh" the UI with new imported data! So the Import.java class have to be an Activity to update the ListView(UI) ?

Comment: We have no way of knowing this. Also I am not seeing that the activity object is used in the function in the first place. Are you sure that you need it? Try removing it and then simply calling it like this: updatelv();

Comment: Well i'm having a FC when removing (activity) when pressing import menu button! I think that i'll change all import.java class to an Activity!